# Trouble with pd.set_option

Tags: python, pandas

The below code doesn't work to display all columns (17). I get all the rows but only the first 4 columns and the next 4 are printed at the bottoms with all the rows again and so on and so forth.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Angéla\Downloads\world_population.csv")
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 350)

print(df)
```

I tried using `df = df.to_string()` but I don't want to use that because I need to manipulate the data and I get string related error message.

Why is `pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)` not working properly?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the `display.width` option should to the trick.

```
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 20)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 350)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    f"c{i}": list(range(5))
    for i in range(17)
})

print(df)
```

**Output.**

```
   c0  c1  c2  c3  c4  c5  c6  c7  c8  c9  c10  c11  c12  c13  c14  c15  c16
0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0    0    0    0    0    0    0
1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1
2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2   2    2    2    2    2    2    2    2
3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3   3    3    3    3    3    3    3    3
4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4   4    4    4    4    4    4    4    4
```

**Documentation of `display.width` option.**

> ```
> display.width: [default: 80] [currently: 1000]
> : int
>         Width of the display in characters. In case python/IPython is running in
>         a terminal this can be set to None and Pandas will correctly auto-detect the
>         width.
>         Note that the IPython notebook, IPython qtconsole, or IDLE do not run in a
>         terminal and hence it is not possible to correctly detect the width.
> ```